# Character encoding from Scala ProcessBuilder

Tags: scala, utf-8

When I run this command from the command prompt, I get correctly decoded UTF-8 characters:

```
gpg --decrypt somefile.csv.zip.gpg | bsdtar -xf - --to-stdout
```

When I take this command, and run it from Scala, like this:

```
val stream = s"gpg --decrypt $filename" #| "bsdtar -xf - --to-stdout"
val output = stream.!!
```

I get scrambled Unicode characters (e.g. Wolfg�ng instead of Wolfgäng)

I can't see which steps loses the character encoding. Where does it happen, and how can I avoid it?

OS = Linux Mint.

Comment: What O.S. are you executing this on?

Comment: Linux Mint, added it to the question.

Comment: I've not found the answer but you can workaround by instead of doing stream.!! do stream #> someOutputStream !